# Is it possible to limit a BaseX server maximum memory consumption?

Tags: basex

Is it possible to hardly limit a maximum memory consumption of a BaseX server instance process (something like a `cache_size` option in MongoDB) avoiding getting `Java heap space` errors simultaneously? Or, in the current implementation, it's required for the process to be able to allocate memory enough for storing a whole data set of the currently accessed database?

In the official documentation I've found nothing more than [the following statement](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Start_Scripts) related to memory usage:

> If BaseX terminates with an Out of Memory error, you can assign more RAM via the -Xmx flag (see below).

Comment: You might consider [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) as a more appropriate forum, since this is more a question about configuring a service than developing software.

Comment: (That said, certainly one doesn't need to be able to store the full dataset in memory -- unless running queries that force same).

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for your advice, but as far as I can see, the BaseX community is relatively small and there are no existing tags and questions related to BaseX at Server Fault at all. Therefore, I suppose that it's more likely to get an answer here.

Comment: If you wanted the place you were most likely to get an answer, you would have asked on the mailing list. If so, I missed your post.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Unfortunately, I was not aware of the existence of this mailing list. Thanks!